# why my interrupt callback got slow with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, embedded, raspberry-pi3, interrupt-handling

I am interfacing rotary encoder with raspberry Pi using the interrupt method and want to show its value on `tkinter` `Label`.
1st I tested my interrupt callback function with main, where my rotary encoder works perfectly i.e. counter=1000 in one rotation of encoder but when I add the `tkinter` part it slows down i.e. counter=800 in one rotation of encoder.
I think there is some issue with the way of handling `tkinter` function, but not able to trace the issue.
Here I am providing my two different codes with output.

```
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep
import math
import Adafruit_MCP4725
dac=Adafruit_MCP4725.MCP4725(address=0x61)
a=22
b=23
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(a,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(b,GPIO.IN)

clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)

def my_callback(channel):
   global clkLastState
   global counter
   clkState=GPIO.input(a)
   if clkState != clkLastState:
           dtState=GPIO.input(b)
           if dtState != clkState:
              counter +=1
           else:
              counter -=1
           text=str(counter/2)
           print (text[0:-2])
   clkLastState=clkState
  # sleep(0.001)
   #finally:
counter=0
clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)
def main():
 global counter
 try:
#  GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
  while (1):
     print(counter/2)
     dac.set_voltage(int(counter/2))
     vlt=int(counter/2)/4096*5.0
     print(vlt)
     sleep(1)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("end it")
  GPIO.cleanup() 
GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
#input("enter anything")
if __name__=='__main__':
 # input("do") 
  main()
```

This is the code where it is working as per encoder specification.

```
955
955
956
956
957
957
958
958
959
959.0
1.170654296875
```

Here program with tkinter.

```
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
a=22
b=23
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(a,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(b,GPIO.IN)
root=tk.Tk()
clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)

def my_callback(channel):
   global clkLastState
   global counter
   clkState=GPIO.input(a)
   if clkState != clkLastState:
           dtState=GPIO.input(b)
           if dtState != clkState:
              counter +=1
           else:
              counter -=1
           text=str(counter/2)
           print (text[0:-2])
           var.set(text)
   clkLastState=clkState
  # sleep(0.001)
counter=0
clkLastState=GPIO.input(a)
GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
print (counter)
var=tk.IntVar()
L1=tk.Label(root,bg="orange",fg="red",textvariable=var)
L1.pack()
# var.set(counter)
# root.after(500,main)
root.geometry("100x100")
root.mainloop()
#var=tk.IntVar()
#L1=tk.Label(root,bg="orange",fg="red",textvariable=var)
#L1.pack()  
#GPIO.add_event_detect(23,GPIO.BOTH,callback=my_callback)
input("enter anything")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

And here is its output.

```
759
760
761
762
763
763
```

For more details, here is my encoder datasheet<http://dien-congnghiep.com/upload/ls_mecapion/encoder_ls_mecapion_s40.pdf>

Comment: You have called `dac.set_voltage(...)` repeatedly in the first program (without `tkinter`), but not in the one with `tkinter`.  Is it the cause of the difference?

Comment: @acw1668,as per prog counter increment and decrements by interrupt callback function,so in both case counter should be same .only diff is in 1st prog i am putting counter value on `dac.set_voltage(...)` and in 2nd prog i am putting on `var.set(..)`.As per my application i want to show counter value on tkinter ,So am i using tkinter in wrong way?

Comment: @Adee It seems concurent running `tkinter.mainloop()` and `GPIO event loop` slows down. Both are using `Thread` and have to share one cpu. Try to run either on in a own `Process`.

Comment: @stovfl,Thats what i am thinking also,but as per application i need tkinter window ,thats why i select raspberry pi as it is powerful,because my 8 bit nuvoton micro controller work perfectly with same encoder and other interrupt event.

Comment: @stovfl,I am not getting your comment "Try to run either on in a own Process".Can u please give a small demonstration for it.

Comment: ***"not getting your comment"***: I advise about [multiprocessing-vs-threading-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580)